# GridView with images aligned bottom in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, android-relativelayout

I've searched this forum up and down and found different solutions but none of them have worked as expected. I even tried looking at the Shelves project that's open sourced and that seemed much too involved for what I'm trying to achieve here.

I have a screen with a bookcase/bookshelf background and have it scrolling as desired with the code below. My RelativeLayout height does not seem to be honored and changing it from 100dp to 200dp makes no difference. I basically need each row in the GridView to be the exact same height and vertically align the thumbnail image bottom so that the image sites on the bookshelf. I sort of achieved this by hardcoding the layout width/height for the ImageView itself. I've tried using a background color so that I can see what's going on but I still fail to achieve a consistent look. I'm also trying to scale the images down to a consistent size, let's say 100x100 even though the images will be different shapes (some are squares and some are rectangles). I also can't seem to get the image to bottom align in the RelativeLayout which builds the cell even though I'm using the android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" attribute.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think I'm close although what I've come up with may be a total hack :-/

Here is a link to a screenshot of what I have working now, with the blue background color for debugging/testing purposes.

[BookShelf Screenshot](https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.alexandriamedia.web/device-2012-06-28-210902.png)

```
/res/layout/titles.xml

<com.alex.android.view.BookShelfView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_titles_grid_view"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="25dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"/>

ImageAdapter 

class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return borrowedAssets.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return borrowedAssets.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return borrowedAssets.get(position).getContentId();
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View cellView;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            cellView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.title_cell, null);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) cellView.findViewById(R.id.title_thumbnail);
            new DownloadImageTask(image).execute(getString(R.string.thumbnails_server_url)+borrowedAssets.get(position).getThumbnail());
        } else {
            cellView = convertView;
        }

        return cellView;
    }
}

/res/layout/title_cell.xml


<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/title_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/blue_color"
            android:contentDescription="thumbnail"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My RelativeLayout height does not seem to be honored and changing it from 100dp to 200dp makes no difference

In your custom adapter use the `parent` parameter in the inflate method like this:

```
cellView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.title_cell, parent, false);
```

Also keep in mind that in your current `getView` method you set the image for the `ImageView` **only** when the there isn't a recycled `View`(`convertView == null`) so when you have a recycled `View` you'll end up with the same image.